# StringBuilder Value cannot be Null ASP .NET MVC4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I get error when i am going to create Stringbuilder object "Value cannot be null" 
here is Error snapshot

[image]

and here is code

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) throw (new ArgumentNullException("username"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("");

        foreach (char c in username)
        {
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
                sb.Append(c);
            else
                sb.Append("_").Append((int)c);
        }
```

Comment: why do you want to append empty value ?

Comment: I guess `username` is null. Sometims VS will show error in next line.

Comment: use ``sb.AppendLine();``

Comment: appending value is just for testing but error is before append empty value

Answer (score 6):

The VS debugger sometimes shows the exception helper on the next line.  In this case, `username` is null and you seeing your own exception from the previous line.

After a bit more research, I suspect this behavior is caused by the debugger's "[break on user-unhandled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2008/12/31/exceptions-dialog-explained-or-what-does-user-unhandled-mean.aspx)" feature.  The exception does not count as being user-unhandled until you have moved out of the scope which generated it (in this case the `If` statement).